# Can source code PPA be safely deleted?

Tags: ppa, software-sources

So I was wondering.. Whenever you add an PPA, you always get 2 entries. One "normal" PPA and a source code PPA (the one that says (source) at the end of the line). Since I am normally not interested in the source code, can the source code entries be safely deleted from the PPA list? I like to keep things clean and might even improve the speed when updating.. :P

Comment: Probably it's ok, but realistically how much time can you gain from deleting the source line? 0.01 seconds?, it takes more time to download Translation files than anything else.

Comment: Yeah, probably not a whole lot but again, I don't like to have that list cluttered with double entries. It's just to keep things nice and tidy I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need the source code for some reason (curiosity, etc.), yes, they can be safely removed.

Comment: Alright then I'll go ahead and do that. thanks for the answer. :)